# Git -> cannot access parent directories: bad address

Tags: git, github

I recently created a new private repository on Github and am trying to push files into it.  I am using Git CMD to push this repo.

I have used the following commands in this order from within my project's local file directory:

**git init 

git add . 

git commit -m "First commit" 

git remote add origin "GITHUB REPO URL" 

git push -u origin master**

When I try to push this repo, I get the following error:

**shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: bad address**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was actually a permissions issue.  Originally I was accessing my project from a protected drive, so the parent directories could not be accessed from GitHub.

So for anyone who runs into this problem, just copy your project into C:\ and then push it onto GitHub from there.